# How to group by a key and sum other keys with Ramda?

Tags: ramda.js

Suppose I have an array of objects like this:

```
[
{'prop_1': 'key_1', 'prop_2': 23, 'prop_3': 45},
{'prop_1': 'key_1', 'prop_2': 56, 'prop_3': 10},
{'prop_1': 'key_2', 'prop_2': 10, 'prop_3': 5},
{'prop_1': 'key_2', 'prop_2': 6, 'prop_3': 7}
]
```

I would like to group by the first property and sum the values of the other properties, resulting in an array like this:

```
[
{'prop_1': 'key_1', 'prop_2': 79, 'prop_3': 55},
{'prop_1': 'key_2', 'prop_2': 16, 'prop_3': 12}
]
```

What is the correct way to do this using Ramda?
I have attempted to use the following:

```
R.pipe(
R.groupBy(R.prop('prop_1')),
R.values,
R.reduce(R.mergeWith(R.add), {})
)
```

But this sums also the value of 'prop_1'.

Comment: Can you demonstrate that you've tried something yourself?

Comment: Sorry, I have included my attempt and why it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to map the groups, and then reduce each group. Check the values of the currently merged keys. If the value is a Number add the values. If not just return the 1st value:

```js
const { pipe, groupBy, prop, values, map, reduce, mergeWith, ifElse, is, add, identity } = R

const fn = pipe(
  groupBy(prop('prop_1')),
  values,
  map(reduce(
    mergeWith(ifElse(is(Number), add, identity)),
    {}
  ))
)

const data = [{"prop_1":"key_1","prop_2":23,"prop_3":45},{"prop_1":"key_1","prop_2":56,"prop_3":10},{"prop_1":"key_2","prop_2":10,"prop_3":5},{"prop_1":"key_2","prop_2":6,"prop_3":7}]

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: Note that `ifElse (foo, bar, identity)` might be better written `when (foo, bar)`.  Similarly, there is `unless (foo, bar)` in place of `ifElse (foo, identity, bar)`.

Comment: `when` was exactly what I tried in the 1st place. However, the result becomes a function, while the `ifElse` works.

Comment: That's right.  I'd forgotten that `when` and `unless` are unary.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

If and *only* if you know the keys in advance, you could opt for something "simpler" (of course YMMV):

- `reduceBy` takes a function similar to `Array#reduce`
- Use `prop('prop_1')` as a "group by" clause

*(It should be relatively straightforward to extract the values out of the object to get the final array.)*

```js
console.log(

reduceBy
  ( (acc, obj) =>
      ({ prop_1: obj.prop_1
       , prop_2: acc.prop_2 + obj.prop_2
       , prop_3: acc.prop_3 + obj.prop_3
       })
  // acc initial value
  , { prop_1: ''
    , prop_2: 0
    , prop_3: 0
    }
  // group by clause
  , prop('prop_1')
  , data
  )

);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {reduceBy, prop} = R;</script>
<script>
const data = [{'prop_1': 'key_1', 'prop_2': 23, 'prop_3': 45}, {'prop_1': 'key_1', 'prop_2': 56, 'prop_3': 10}, {'prop_1': 'key_2', 'prop_2': 10, 'prop_3': 5}, {'prop_1': 'key_2', 'prop_2': 6, 'prop_3': 7}];
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not as simple as that from Ori Drori.  And I'm not sure whether that's a good thing.  This seems to more closely fit the requirements, especially if "and sum the values of the other properties" is a simplification of actual requirements.  This tries to keep the key property and then combine the others based on your function

```js
const data = [
  {'prop_1': 'key_1', 'prop_2': 23, 'prop_3': 45},
  {'prop_1': 'key_1', 'prop_2': 56, 'prop_3': 10},
  {'prop_1': 'key_2', 'prop_2': 10, 'prop_3': 5},
  {'prop_1': 'key_2', 'prop_2': 6, 'prop_3': 7}
]

const transform = (key, combine) => pipe (
  groupBy (prop (key)),
  map (map (omit ([key]))),
  map (combine),
  toPairs,
  map (([key, obj]) => ({prop_1: key, ...obj}))
)

console .log (
  transform ('prop_1', reduce(mergeWith (add), {})) (data)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
<script> const {pipe, groupBy, prop, map, omit, reduce, mergeWith, add, toPairs, lift, merge, head, objOf, last} = R </script>
```

If you have a fetish for point-free code that last line could be written as

```js
 map (lift (merge) (pipe (head, objOf(key)), last))
```

But as we are already making points of `key` and `obj`, I see no reason.  Yes, we could change that, but I think it would become pretty ugly code.

There might well be something to be said for a more `reduce`-like version, where instead of passing such a `combine` function, we pass something that combines two values as well as a way to get the initial value.  That's left as an exercise for later.